# Resize image and drag position using jquery and saving the output to html

Tags: jquery, draggable, image-resizing, masking

I'm trying to build a little tool that enables me to take an image, put a PNG transparent mask over it, then scale and drag the image in place to get it perfectly positioned/sized within the mask.

Here is the jquery.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var globalElement_width;
var globalElement_height;
$(document).ready(function(){
$img=$('.canvas img');
globalElement_width=$img.width();
globalElement_height=$img.height();

$( ".slider" ).slider({
    step: 1, 
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 0,
    slide: function( event, ui )
    {
        resize_img(ui.value);
    }
});

$('.canvas img').draggable();

});
function resize_img(val) {
var width=globalElement_width;
var zoom_percen=width * 0.5; // Maximum zoom 50%
var ASPECT = zoom_percen / 50;
var zoom_value = val / 2;
var size= width + ASPECT * zoom_value;

$img = $('.canvas img');
$img.stop(true).animate({
    width: size
}, 1);
}

});
```

I have 2 issues (in addition to the code probably being pretty janky)

1. I want the image to initially load behind the mask at actual size centered and have the slider allow for scaling smaller, not larger as I have it now. I want to ensure the image never goes above it's actual dimension to avoid distortion. The slider should slide to the left, representing decrease in size, not to the right as it does.
2. Once i get the placement right, i want to be able to click a button and then output the new HTML/CSS/JS for the newly resized and positioned graphic. Then I can just take this code and put it into a site and show the image and mask without any UX to resize/position/etc. Just hard coded in that exact state I generated.

Any help is greatly appreciated... this is as far as I can get cobbling various pieces of code together. Also, suggestions on cleanup of what I have is encouraged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a buddy help me out (Thanks Yadid!).

```
/*
this function returns the HTML of an object (same as object.html() - but with the wrapping       element too)
*/
$.fn.outerHTML = function(){

// IE, Chrome & Safari will comply with the non-standard outerHTML, all others (FF) will have a fall-back for cloning
return (!this.length) ? this : (this[0].outerHTML || (
  function(el){
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
      var contents = div.innerHTML;
      div = null;
      return contents;
})(this[0]));

}

function saveEverything(){
var html = $('.canvas').outerHTML();
    alert(html);
    //Save "html" somewhere    
}


$(window).load(function () {
    var globalElement_width;
    var globalElement_height;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*
        the problem was that you were trying to get the size of the image before the image was actually loaded
        - which returns wrong dimensions (the image is not there yet, so javascript can't get the width/height of the photo)

    to solve it, we first need to initialize the image tag before we do anything -  
    we can do that by loading a blank image to it - "about:blank" (a 'blank' URL)                

    then bind to the img tag's "load" event - this event is fired after the photo is loaded and fully rendered
    - once you get this event, you can read the dimension of the image

    then,after we bind to the event, we can load the actual photo.
    we do that by changing the "src" attribute of the <img> tag to the URL of the image you want to load        
    */
    $img = $('.canvas img').bind("load",function(){
        globalElement_width = $img.width();
        globalElement_height = $img.height();
        $(".slider").slider({
            step: 0.01, /* Changed from 0 to 100, to 0 to 1, with 1% steps (ie 0.01) . this will make the calculations easier */
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            value: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                resize_img(ui.value);
            }
        });

        //now that we have the right dimension, we can center the image 
        center_img();

        $('.canvas img').draggable();
    });
    $img.attr("src","http://media-cache-ec4.pinimg.com/736x/42/07/08/420708fc70c76f89c07bc93d13e6c479.jpg");
});

function center_img(){
    //get the size of the canvas, substract the size of the image then divide by 2 which center it
    var c = $('.canvas');
    var l = (c.width() - c.find('img').width())/2;
    var t = (c.height() - c.find('img').height())/2;            

    c.find('img').css({position:"absolute", top:t, left:l});    
}
// the val will be anywhere between 0 to 1, so we just need to multiply that number with the original size of the image
function resize_img(val) {

    // we get size of container so image wont be smaller than container
    var w = $('.canvas').width();

    // then use Math.min and Math.max, which return the minimum and maximum between 2 numbers
    $('.canvas img').stop(true).animate({
        width: Math.max(w, globalElement_width * Math.min(1,val))
    },1, function(){
        center_img();
    });
}

}); //]]>
```